# set backupcopy=yes doesn't still writes the file twice

Tags: vimrc, buffers, save, backup

I'm trying to understand and eventually fix the following behavior: when I save a file using VIM, it triggers the `change`/`write` event twice.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10, and I created an empty `.vimrc` file to make sure that no plugins create this behavior.

So, I open the `foo.txt` file:

```
vim -u .vimrc foo.txt
```

And then using `inotify-tools` (installed using `sudo apt install inotify-tools`) I run the following command:

```
inotifywait -m foo.txt
```

Then in VIM I do `:w`, triggering the save. I can see the following output:

```
$ inotifywait -m foo.txt 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
foo.txt OPEN 
foo.txt ACCESS 
foo.txt CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE 
foo.txt MODIFY 
foo.txt OPEN 
foo.txt MODIFY 
foo.txt CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 
foo.txt ATTRIB
```

After setting `backupcopy=yes` I can see EXACTLY the same behavior. I tried to add it in the `vimrc` and restart VIM, but there was no change at all.

How can I fix this?

Everyone on the internet recommends using `backupcopy=yes` which for some reason doesn't fix the issue on my machine. Why?

Is there any other workaround?

---

In my original `~/.vimrc` I do have this at the end of the file:

```
" Node.js fs.watch
set backupdir=~/.vim/tmp,.
set directory=~/.vim/tmp,.
set backupcopy=yes
```

Doesn't seem to make any change (I do have the `~/.vim/tmp` dir).

Comment: Did you set `backup` as well?

Comment: @laktak Not sure about the `backup` you're mentioning, but I do have `backupdir` and `directory`, see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `backupcopy=no` Vim will try to rename the file. If this fails it will work the same way as `backupcopy=yes`.

For example (with `strace`):

```
rename("test.txt", "/tmp/test.txt~") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

But in any case, Vim will only write to the file once:

```
set backupcopy=no

rename("test.txt", "test.txt~")   = 0
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 3
write(3, "a\nbb\n\nccc\ndddd\n\neeeee\n", 22) = 22
close(3)                                = 0


set backupcopy=yes

open("test.txt", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("test.txt~", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW, 0644) = 5
read(3, "a\nbb\n\nccc\ndddd\n\neeeee\n", 8192) = 22
write(5, "a\nbb\n\nccc\ndddd\n\neeeee\n", 22) = 22
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 3
write(3, "a\nbb\n\nccc\ndddd\n\neeeee\n", 22) = 22
close(3)                                = 0
```

Maybe you have a plugin/autocmd that is responsible for the second write. Test with `vim -u NONE`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. On Ubuntu, set backupcopy=yes was set and yet multiple file writes were happening. I disabled all plugins and saw there was only a single write. I added each plugin back one-by-one and found that `polyglot` broke it. It then ended up being `ElmCast/elm-vim` which is installed by polyglot which does the double file writes. I turned it off via `let g:elm_format_autosave = 0` and things worked again.